# Django - What is the best way to have multi level status before login

Tags: python, django

I have one scenario, there is a user registration and it should have multiple status(may be is_active - but this is boolean by default)

1. List item Code - 0 -> Pending for Email Confirmation
2. List item Code - 1 -> Account Activated/Active(Only after email confirmed admin will approve it)
3. List item Code - 2 -> Email Confirmed

I am using django allauth, I was browsing to achieve it, but unable to find some close match of it. For your info I also have `Profile OnetoOne model for User model`

**Updated**

```
class CustomConfirmEmailView(ConfirmEmailView):
    def get(self):
        raise Exception('GET')
    def post(self,*args,**kwargs):
        raise Exception('POST')
```

**Settings file**

```
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
```

Comment: Why you can't just add field `is_confirmed`?

Comment: @vishes_shell Yes so where should I add it and how to implement it in login logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create custom `User` or custom `Profile`(i believe that it's better with custom `Profile`, to avoid messing with django `User`):

```
from itertools import compress

class CustomProfile(Profile):
    is_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def status(self):
        return next(compress(['Pending', 'Active', 'Confirmed'], 
                             [not self.is_confirmed, not self.is_confirmed and self.user.is_active, self.confirmed and self.user.is_active]))
```

You can see that i added `@property` that would answer your question about user status.

But for setting `is_confirmed` you need to look at the sources, [docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#e-mail-verification) lead you to [`allauth.account.views.ConfirmEmailView`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py#L225) view.

And i think that you need to override `post` method.

```
class CustomConfirmEmailView(ConfirmEmailView):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = confirmation = self.get_object()
        confirmation.confirm(self.request)
        get_adapter(self.request).add_message(
            self.request,
            messages.SUCCESS,
            'account/messages/email_confirmed.txt',
            {'email': confirmation.email_address.email})
        if app_settings.LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION:
            resp = self.login_on_confirm(confirmation)
            if resp is not None:
                return resp
        profile = confirmation.email_address.user.profile
        profile.is_confirmed = True
        profile.save()
        redirect_url = self.get_redirect_url()
        if not redirect_url:
            ctx = self.get_context_data()
            return self.render_to_response(ctx)
        return redirect(redirect_url)
```

And then you need to put that View in url.

That's it. Sure i didn't run it. But the logic is here.

Comment: Thanks. I will check this now. As you said I have separate `Profile` only I did not mess up anything with auth user so far

Comment: One more thing is missed I have also asked how to check in login whether it is is_confirmed or not?

Comment: Yeah, Use that `Profile`, it's easier with it. As i know system won't let you login unless you user `is_active`.

Comment: Got it thanks will give out a try and mark as answered with upvote

Comment: Should I use any signals to do it, because post as well as get does not works on email confirmation

Comment: What do you mean not working? Is that throw some kind of error, or it's not saving `profile`?

Comment: Please check my updated question, when I click activation link it is not showing my exception message

Comment: @overflow you need to put url with your custom view above urls that include django allauth.

Comment: I did it but still we are missing something, when I enable email confirmation still account is active and account_emailaddress field it is not verified and so after verifying it automatically logs in

Comment: @overflow have you disabled `LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION` ? Look at the post method, you can remove part with `LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION` , because if it's true then is login the user and return response. You understand what I'm trying to say?

Comment: @overflow glad that helped.) Future suggestion: it's easier to go to source code and understand what happends there. Cheers!:)

Comment: @overflow definitely new question.

Comment: New question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068295/django-inlineformset-capform-object-has-no-attribute-cleaned-data see if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decorators` for these kinds of scenarios. Decorators are just methods that accepts another method as argument. What you have to do is to `pass the get/post or any other methods together with its arguments to decorator` then check for email confirmation/account active.

```
from functools import wraps
from .permissions import is_admin_or_manager
from .utils import get_user_on_user_identifier


def is_manager(method):
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_identifier = kwargs.get('user_identifier') if kwargs.get('user_identifier') else args[0]
    user = get_user_on_user_identifier(user_identifier)
    if user:
        if is_admin_or_manager(user):
            return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return {'status': 403, 'description': 'Only Manager/Admin roles can create items.'}
    else:
        return {'status': 404, 'description': 'No user with given username/email exists.'}
return wrapper

class PermissionException(Exception):
    pass
```

And in your views,

```
class Home(View):
    @is_manager
    def get(self, request):
        ...
```

Above code exemplifies on usage of decorators. In your case, pass method with args. get user from request arg passed to decorator, then check if email is confirmed/ account is activated. If not return message using [django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/) json/string can be also be used to pass maessages.

In case you want to use the same with class based views consider [mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/mixins/). You can override `dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` method. I think using decorators/mixins will be better since you do your checks on every views that you write with one line of code.